# Primefaces downloadFile java.io.IOException: Stream Closed after second time

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have issue with primefaces 5.0 component p:fileDownload , I have following bean store `DefaultStreamedContent` , and I get the value stored to download it simply :

Bean :

```
public class EBMail implements Serializable {
    private DefaultStreamedContent attachment;
    // @ here setter and getter too .
}
```

and from XHTML file :

```
<p:commandLink ajax="false" value="Download Attachment" rendered="#{mbMail.attachment != null}">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{mbMail.attachment}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

I get mail attachment file for first time, in 2nd time I get the following exception :

```
WARNING: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
javax.faces.FacesException: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at org.primefaces.component.filedownload.FileDownloadActionListener.processAction(FileDownloadActionListener.java:87)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:243)
    at org.primefaces.component.filedownload.FileDownloadActionListener.processAction(FileDownloadActionListener.java:77)
    ... 30 more

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [FacesServlet] in context with path [/faces] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:213)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextImpl.java:846)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.createPartialResponseWriter(PartialViewContextImpl.java:504)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.access$300(PartialViewContextImpl.java:79)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$DelayedInitPartialResponseWriter.getWrapped(PartialViewContextImpl.java:642)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PartialResponseWriter.java:120)
    at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext$OmniPartialResponseWriter.startDocument(OmniPartialViewContext.java:270)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:201)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:126)
    at javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handle(ExceptionHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I'm running on JFS 2.2.7 , Primefaces 5.0 , I upload file into bean my issue when I download it for 2nd time, even for another object 'mail' .

Any solution, I looked after many solutions around nothing helped me or I've already tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue finally, I make new class store my data, and action that prepare stream to download from my class object, and when download file I read bytes from my class bytes, like the following:

Class:

```
public class Attachment implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String encoding;
    private byte[] data;

    // ... Setters and getters ...

    public Attachment () {
        this.encoding = "UTF-8";
    }

}
```

Bean:

```
public class MailBean implements Serializable {
    // alot of properties
    private Attachment attachment;
    // setters and getters
}
```

Managed Bean :

```
public class MailManagedBean implements Serializable {
    private DefaultStreamedContent attachmentToDownload;
    private MailBean mail;
    // @ here setter and getter too .

    public void prepare() {
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(mail.getAttachment.getData());
        attachmentToDownload = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, mail.getAttachment.getType(), mail.getAttachment.getName(), mail.getAttachment.getEncoding());
    }
}
```

In XHTML file (I added action) :

```
<p:commandLink ajax="false" value="Download Attachment" 
    rendered="#{mbMail.mail.attachment != null}" action="#{mbMail.prepare()}">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{mbMail.attachmentToDownload}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public StreamedContent getExportFile() {
Field field = exportFile.getStream().getClass().getDeclaredField("path");
field.setAccessible(true);
String path = (String)field.get(exportFile.getStream());
InputStream tempStream = new FileInputStream(path);
exportFile = new DefaultStreamedContent(tempStream,exportFile.getContentType(), exportFile.getName());
return exportFile;
}
```