# How to make a downloadable commandLink for any content type (pdf/zip/docx/jpeg etc)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to create a downloadable link.I use primefaces 5.0 and jsf 2.2.I have some files (pdf,zip/rar,docx,jpeg etc) and I want to share this files on data table with commandLink. Only available to download a file(have a specific content type) in google.(example:[download only a pdf](http://balusc.blogspot.com.tr/2006/05/pdf-handling.html)).But how can I do that for any content type file?
All my files in

```
 c://uploads/files/dir1/foo.zip
 ---------""------/dir2/boo.pdf
 ---------""------/dir3/doo.jpeg etc.
```

You can see below similar code dependent of the specific content-type.

```
    private StreamedContent file;

 public FileDownloadView() {        
        InputStream stream = ((ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getResourceAsStream("/resources/demo/images/optimus.jpg");
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "image/jpg", "downloaded_optimus.jpg");
    }

    public StreamedContent getFile() {
        return file;
    }
```

you can see on this part:

```
DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "image/jpg", "downloaded_optimus.jpg");
```

only download "image/jpg".I want to be independent in this section.Is mandatory a separate code for each content type?
I want to share this files regardless of content type in data table.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve and your "code" isn't helpful at all. Can you try to elaborate your question a little bit pls? :)

Comment: thanks for reply.I edited.Please look again.

Comment: what if you create new bean to store data like file type and name and data ? look at my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041523/primefaces-downloadfile-java-io-ioexception-stream-closed-after-second-time

Comment: Looks like a nice solution.But how to set mail object with properties?where?If you add this to your solution, I will mark as answer.@Al-Mothafar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create new bean like :

```
public class MyFile {

    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String encoding;
    private String path;

    // ... Setters and getters ...

    public Attachment () {
        this.encoding = "UTF-8";
    }

}
```

In your managed bean

```
private DefaultStreamedContent streamToDownload;
    private MyFile myFile;
    // @ here setter and getter too .

    public void prepareForDownlaod() {
    InputStream stream = ((ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getResourceAsStream(myFile.getPath());

        streamToDownload= new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, myFile.getType(), myFile.getName(), myFile.getEncoding());
    }
```

And in xhtml file :

```
<p:commandLink ajax="false" value="Download" action="#{managedBean.prepareForDownlaod()}">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{managedBean.streamToDownload}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

Try this I hope this will work for you.

**EDIT**
My solution for stored data like from data stored in database, or you can set the file type with `externalContext.getMimeType`, you can refer to BalusC answer for last case.

Comment: Maybe you can use `<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{file}" target="#{managedBean.myFile}" />` if you want to display all the downloadable files in `<p:dataTable>`.